# Rails pattern for action(update, delete, etc) & error checking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, restful-url

I am new to Rails, so I am wondering if there is a known pattern for the below (my Google skills are failing here).

All of my Rest controllers follow the basic pattern of:

Check if the item exists --> Fetch the item if it does --> return error if it doesn't --> do something if it does --> check if the action failed --> return error if failed --> successes if it did not. So two actions, and two error checks. My QUESTION IS: Is this a good correct pattern, or should I be doing something different?

Example of "Destroy" method:

```
def destroy 
  if @team = fetch_team
    if @team.destroy
      render json: {message: "team: '#{params[:id]}' deleted"}, status: 200
    else
      render json: {message: "error: #{@team.errors.full_messages}"}, status: 500
    end          
  else
    render json: {message: "team: '#{params[:id]}' not found"}, status: 404  
  end
end

##

def fetch_team
    Team.find_by(name: params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would refactor some of your logic out of the individual actions to make it DRYer.

First, I would move the check for `fetch_team` into a `before_action` filter. That way you can have Rails run it for multiple actions like `show`, `update`, and `destroy`.

When you call `Team.find_by!` (note the bang), Rails will throw an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception if the record is not found. So you can use `rescue_from` to do what you need to do if the record is not found. That way, again, you don't need to repeat that logic across multiple actions.

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_team, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found # This can be moved to `ApplicationController` if you follow this pattern in ALL of your controllers

  def destroy
    if @team.destroy
      render json: { message: "team: '#{params[:id]}' deleted" }, status: 200
    else
      render json: { message: "error: #{@team.errors.full_messages}" }, status: 500
    end
  end

private

  def find_team
    @team = Team.find_by!(name: params[:id])
  end

  def not_found
    render json: { message: "team: '#{params[:id]}' not found" }, status: 404
  end
end
```

After saying all of this, I think what's defined in `not_found` is very generous. Usually, I'd just let the controller throw its own 404 exception when `find_by!` fails and expect the client to recognize the 404 header and respond accordingly. It's up to you if you want the error message from your example to display though.

Comment: This looks much better, thanks. However it seems I need `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` not `ActiveRecord::NotFound`

Comment: Edited my answer. There's your proof that I coded that entire answer in the browser. At least I was consistent. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's work with the destroy action example:

The common way I have seen is to make the controller destroy action simple like this:

```
def destroy
  @team = Team.find(params[:id]) # first find the object you want to delete 
  @team.destroy # if it's found, call the destroy method on it. if it's not found, you won't get to this line. it'll raise error. 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to teams_url } #this is redirecting to your chosen path once it's destroyed. 
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

But in your views, you'll provide the user the opportunity to change their mind before proceeding with deletion:

`app/views/teams/show.html.erb`

```
<%= link_to 'Delete team', @team class: 'btn btn-primary', method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this team?' } %>
```

This will prompt a pop up message. they can either click `cancel` or proceed with deletion by clicking `ok`